# Tapioca flour pizza crust is gummy?

Tags: pizza, crust

I'm not sure if it's either too thick, not baked alone long enough, or a reactuon to adding a hand made sauce.... [image][image]

Comment: What are the ingredients in the crust?

Comment: In addition to @moscafj, do you have any experience handling tapioca flour? That flour has the *expected* property of getting gummy when heated, especially when it is in a large proportion vs. the other ingredients

Comment: Are you pre-baking the crust, or baking it after adding the toppings?

Comment: Liquid coming off tomatoes, peppers and such would tend to make tapioca gummier.

Comment: @moscafj I added the ingredient and directions in the pictures.

Comment: @Juliana Karasawa Souza this is the first time I've worked with tapioca flour and was wondering. It just caught me off guard.

Comment: @Joe its a bit of both. You pre bake for 16-18 min then add the rest.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger  that's good to know.

Comment: Wow, where did you get that recipe? Tapioca gets gummy, potato starch gets horribly gummy, and gelatin... is gummy. I can’t in my wildest dreams imagine those ingredients turning into anything remotely resembling a pizza crust!

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill - It was from a paleo magazine a friend gave me. It sorta worked.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first things first... as I mentioned in my comment, tapioca flour *gets* gummy when heated. That's *expected*.
In Brazil we do have something called just tapioca, and otherwise known as tapioca crepe that's made with hydrated tapioca flour spread on a pan and heated until all it sticks together and forms a "crepe" of sorts [Picture here, so you can see the gummy inside](https://images.app.goo.gl/2qFaYAzQm9z7DwwJ9)

One more thing about expectations: your recipe is for a crispy crust, it will not get to the same texture as "regular" pizza crust (elastic and fluffy).

A few ways for you to lessen the gummy texture

- Add a leavening agent like baking powder or baking soda. This will aerate the mixture and prevent the tapioca flour from gelatinizing;
- Flip the dough and add the toppings on the side that was in contact with the pan. You know how the cake usually crusts on the bottom and the sides? That will protect your dough from moisture a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks! I was just caught off guard. I'll try adding a leavening next time.